# workaround pex internal class

Tags: pex

Is there any way to make pex work when the classes under test are internal? how about sealed classes?

I mean after all this type of tool is really good for API testing, you are likely to want to keep stuff at least internal sometimes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the test assembly internal visibility through the [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx). Pex will then be able to 'see' internal types and test them.

Comment: There is even a menu item for it in VS 2010 ( i must be blind) Thanks

Comment: When generating a new Pex test project, never versions of Pex automatically adds `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Company.Product.ProjectUnderTest.Tests")]` (plus .Eplorables) in AssemblyInfo.cs. The ProjectUnderTest's internals will then be visible for both the Pex test project and Explorables.

Comment: Oh, and I meant _newer_ versions of Pex adds to ProjectUnderTest's AssemblyInfo.cs.