# Testing Private Method using Pex

Tags: pex

I want to use Pex and Moles in my project.I want to test Private method using Pex.

Is anyone used Pex to test private method?

If we can't test directly, Is there any workaround to test Private method?

Comment: Sign is removed, Please refer the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered by [Peli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14403/peli), one of Pex's authors: [PEX will not work for private and protected methods](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/pex/thread/6400271b-fc4b-4af4-b57e-831d0fd041ec) and [workaround pex internal class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167541/workaround-pex-internal-class).

A few of the alternatives:

1. Don't test private methods.
2. Re-design the logic you are testing to increase testability.
3. Use [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx). Put `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Company.Product.ProjectUnderTest.Tests")]` into `Company.Product.ProjectUnderTest\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs`.

[testing](/questions/tagged/testing) [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)