# Visual Studio 2015 RC Pex creates tests for public methods only

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, automated-tests, pex

I was under the impression that once I have the entry below in my assemblyinfo.cs file

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyAssembliesName")]

, then pex should be able to see all internal methods in my class definition, in addition to the public methods. So, when does Pex not creat unit tests for the internal methods in my class?

Comment: Please see response to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669578/any-idea-how-i-can-run-intellitests-on-internal-classes/32688515#32688515.

Answer (score 4):

The RC version does not yet support exploring non-publicly accessible methods. However, we are addressing this in the next upcoming release. Thank you for your interest in IntelliTest!

Answer (score 2):

The `InternalsVisibleTo` specifies which assembly you're granting access to, not the assembly that is granting the access (which is what you appear to be describing).

So, if you had a production project and a test project, the production project would have the attribute, granting access to the test project.

I haven't used pex with VS2015, but on the face of it, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613263/testing-private-method-using-pex/9140786#9140786) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173837/592182), having the `InternalsVisibleTo` point at your test project should be enough.