# Any idea how I can run Intellitests on "internal" classes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, intellitest

I'm building a library that will be a part of a number of libraries that will be used by an umbrella library to which they all are built with an internalsVisibleTo("{umbrella-library}").

I would like to explore the libraries I'm building with the new Microsoft Intellitest, but seems it doesn't work on internal classes because the methods are not publicly visible (even though they are singularly public).

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can't you make all of the libraries internally visible to the test project as well?

Comment: I guess I have to try a bit harder, I'll give an update asap.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use IntelliTest to explore internal types:
(1) Invoke the "Create IntelliTest" command on the desired method first so that a test project with the required PUT and attributes are emitted.
(2) Next, invoke the Run IntelliTest command either on the desired method or the (just emitted) PUT as usual.

Please see this post (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/25/unit-test-generators-extensibility-hats-off-to-our-community.aspx) for rationale.